# Python : Quickest way to find index of each 1's in a binary data type without using loops

Tags: python, binary

I'm trying to find index of each occurrence of 1 in a binary data type.

For example, after I do a bit wise 'AND' operation between two binary variables:

```
>>> a = 0b1111                                 
>>> b = 0b1011
>>> c = a & b
>>> d = bin(c)
>>> print("Output: ",d)
```

The out put is :

```
Output: '0b1011'
```

Now, is there a quick way to find out the index of each occurrence of '1' ( In this case [0,2,3] ), without using any loops?

Comment: This is a poorly constrained question.  What output would you expect if b was instead `0b0011`?

Comment: I just wanted to show an example of why I want it. if b was 0b0011, the result will be 0b0011 and I would want [2,3] as result, since there is 1 at index 2 and index 3.

Comment: This could be an X Y problem. What do you need that indexes for?

Comment: You can think of it as a bitmap indexing. I am representing my intervals as binary values. So when I 'AND' them, I get the sections where both of them are high. After that, I would like to know, where they are high.

Comment: e = numpy.fromstring(bin(c)[2:], 'u1') - ord('0') to get corresponding array and result =np.where(e)[0] worked for me